# Cannot update pre indexed data via SOLR/CURL

Tags: json, curl, solr

I've performed the following indexation via SOLR/CURL

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/wiki/update -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '
[
{"id" : "book1",
"title" : "American Gods",
"author" : "Neil Gaiman"
}
]'
```

Error appears while updating the data

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/wiki/update -H 'Content-         type:application/json' -d '
[
{"id" : "book1",
"cat" : { "add" : "fantasy" },
"pubyear_i" : { "add" : 2001 },
"ISBN_s" : { "add" : "0-380-97365-0"}
}
]'
```

This is the error

`{"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":0},"error":{"metadata":["error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException","root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],"msg":"undefined field: \"cat\"","code":400}}`

When i delete the following "id" from JSON file "cat" : { "add" : "fantasy" }, the indexation is proceeded.
What is the problem ?

Comment: have you defined the field "cat" in your schema ?

Comment: My guess is that the complaint is about using `add` when there is no value in the field already. `add` is used to append a value to an existing multivalued field. Try using `set` instead.

Comment: @MatsLindh
That didn't work (
As I have mentioned above the issue is about "cat" : { "add" : "fantasy" }.
If I delete this string from the command, the fields will appear via "id=book1" and will be indexed.

Comment: @root545 While creating the core I've used the following command ( create -c wiki -n data_driven_schema_configs" ) so as far as I know the current settings of my core are schemaless. The only field that is defined is "id" field, the other fields are dynamic.

Comment: But does the document exist in the index when you're using `set`? The update commands only work with existing documents, not adding new ones.